# Problems with BLTouch on Ender 3 Pro

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch, z-probe

I have had some issues with my Ender 3 Pro (v4.2.2 motherboard). The BLTouch decided to just probe the air. It had been working quite fine until one day when it stopped. IDK if this helps, but I have dual Z axis installed, and the BLTouch stopped working shortly after I installed it. The actual BLTouch works fine - I tested it under the test section of the menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more information please? When you say it "probed the air" do you mean it 'activated' without touching the buildplate? I have an Ender 3 Pro with the Dual Z upgrade and BLTouch as well, though I upgraded to the BTT SKR MINI E3 V3 board, but prior to the upgrade, I had no issues with running the BLTouch and Dual Z together.

Comment: @EchoTree Sorry, I should have closed the post. I fixed it by hot-gluing the connection wires to the board, as they were a bit loose.